# Reduce MS SQL server log file size

Tags: sql-server-2005

I administer an a MS SQL server 2005 DB. Rececently I have discovered that the log file has grown exceedingly large. It has grown from about 50 MB to 117 GB. What causes this and how do I reduce it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Joeqwerty is right, you need to backup your log files, otherwise they will continue to grow until you run out of disk space.

Depending on your environment, if you don't need the log backups, then you can set your Database's recovery model to "Simple".  This will also help to keep the log files from growing out of control.

HTH, Dan

Comment: ok, so the proper steps is: 1. perform SQL DB maintenance plan - Shrink - On Demand (from DB maintenance plan) 2. perform full backup of the DB 3. set the DB to be simple recovery mode ?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by not backing up and shrinking the log file. You need to backup and then shrink the log.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873235